# Azure App Service, on premises domain and VPN Tunnel

Tags: api, azure, azure-app-service-plans

Is it possible to create a VPN tunnel between on premises domain and Azure App Service? If so, do we get a static IP address to create this tunnel with the App Service?

I don't want to use an Azure VM. I have been researching a way to create this tunnel so all the App Service apps(Web and API apps) act if they are part of the on premises domain. Users can't access these app services unless they are within the on premises domain.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a site-to-site VPN specifically with App Services in mind, but I have done it with VMs and Cloud Services.  It should be configurable via the Azure Portal:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still looking for something for App Service, it looks like all the apps inside the app service plan have the same IP address, so that's my new starting point right now.